# Most ergonomical city shape & design

Tags: construction, travel, infrastructure

I'm designing a city, I want to know what the most efficient city design/shape would be, I think square would be bad because the people in the corners would take too long to get to the city center, while circle may be a bad shape to organised land ownership (curved pieces of land)

Let me know your opinions and why certain shapes may perform better in terms of travel, building & infrastructure.

Comment: This book and it's companions may help you https://books.google.com/books?id=hqkXDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Global+Street+Design+Guide&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP1e-o8YXXAhXD1CYKHVeCBfMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Global%20Street%20Design%20Guide&f=false Specifically the book on urban design may be more helpful. the question covers several courses worth of information. You should narrow it down to a more specific question.

Comment: 1) Efficient for what purpose?  Unless you're a government with dreams of grandeur (e.g. Washington, Brasilia), you don't design cities, they grow, and change as the needs of their inhabitants change.  2) Unless you're building in someplace like the middle of Kansas, your design is going to be strongly affected by topography: rivers, mountains, shorelines, &c.

Comment: Way too broad, but I did not vote to close it. Just provided examples and considerations.

Comment: @ErinThursby If you think the question is "Way too broad" you should VTC the question or edit the question to reduce the scope, not answer it.

Comment: Those Romans... they have spent centuries building cities arranged on a square lattice! How dumb!

Comment: There is an Urban Planning exchange in development [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110962/urban-planning) that might help you but this too-broad for this site.

Comment: Should note that there are 2 very distinct city designs...one city designed before the invent of car, and one city designed post-car.

Comment: @sphennings I thought it was interesting and wanted to give the poster a foundation for answering their own question, by providing examples of past cities and why they were designed the way they were. I didn't think it warranted a close vote from me, but I wanted to poster to know that they should be more specific about parameters. Efficiency means different things to different societies, and we have no idea what it means here, or even what tech we are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of parameters are missing to come up with an answer. What level of technology are we dealing with? Do we have a democratic government or an autocratic one? Is there unfettered use of private property, or is property controlled by a central organization? There are tons of other parameters which will determine what will be considered "efficient". The growth of Exurban "pods" in the United States (city sized constructs without any definitive "city centre") is based on the assumption that people want to own their own residential property and travel "point to point" from their residence to their destination is a good example of how your starting assumptions will determine the outcome.

From a straight efficiency POV, I would think that a compact 3 dimensional structure is most efficient, but that is only looking at factors such as energy utilization (the surface to volume ratio of a 3D structure means heating and cooling the interior of the structure will take less energy). Transportation is also much easier, since things will be a short distance away, either on your level, or an elevator ride up or down.

This sort of construct was popularized as the "[Arcology](https://arcosanti.org/theory/arcology/main.html)" by [Paolo Soleri](https://infogalactic.com/info/Paolo_Soleri). The basic idea was to make the human habitation as compact and energy efficient as possible (including recycling and reusing the waste products of the inhabitants), leaving large areas of land open and allowing it to be used for agriculture or to revert to wilderness. Arcologies were designed from village sized to massive city sized constructs, which could house the population of New York City in a few megastructures scattered over the newly rewilded six boroughs.

[image]

*Arcvillage, designed to house 30,000 people*

[image]

*Cross section of the Hexahedron, designed to house 170,000 people, with the Empire State Building to scale*

So assuming the political, economic and social system is able to support building and housing tens to hundreds of thousands of people in kilometre high "condominiums" and attend to all the issues such structures could cause, then a 3D arcology would seem to be the most "efficient" structure. for an urbanized population.

Answer (score 0):

If you have public mass transit and no private vehicles, and lots of land, a wheel with a central hub and the spokes are residential areas, a few streets wide. One mass transit line down each hub. Services would be one line down each hub. In-ground delivery system, same thing. All transit goes into a central switching station in the hub, and back out another spoke. Local commercial stores along the spokes, main shopping in the hub. Offices at the end of each hub, separate from commercial at the other end. Between the spokes, public park land and recreational. In selective areas between the spokes, industry that requires large footprint infrastructure. No parking lots, anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this all depends on the world you are building, including time period and vehicles. It's a very broad question indeed.

If you want walkability design will change. If you want fast transport using cars, design will change.

Most cities grow organically, and most haphazardly.

But there are exceptions.

[image: Washington D.C.]

This image is the city of Washington, D.C. Because it was an empty piece of land, the designers of the city could plan it from scratch. As you can see, some of it was shaped by the peculiarities of the landscape.

City design is all about what the city designers WANT out of it.

Ergonomics takes into account human usage, but there are a thousand different ways you could define that.

D.C. was built with a few things in mind.

1) As a showcase of a newly formed government, to create tradition and grandiosity. So space for monuments was built into the plan.

2) Easy to understand grid/naming system.

> The plan specified that most streets would be laid out in a grid. To form the grid, some streets (later named for letters of the alphabet) would travel in an east–west direction, while others (named for numbers) would travel in a north-south direction. Diagonal broader avenues, later named after the states of the Union, crossed the north/south-east/west grid.[27][33][34][35] The diagonal avenues intersected with the north–south and east–west streets at circles and rectangular plazas that would later honor notable Americans and provide open space [SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Enfant_Plan)

It might be good if you zeroed in on what this society wants out of the space and why. If it's about commerce, or travel, or what.

There are loads of historic examples. City planning has been going on for quite a while.

Here's what these old-time cities had in common:
Grid like plans. The Greeks and the Romans used an orthogonal grid set-up, when they actually planned a city. This was to make things easy. Buildings also tend to be square, so there's that. But when they didn't plan, of course it was pretty chaotic.

There are lots of different theories as far as urban planning is concerned.

The **rational planning movement** (1890–1960) was all about exposure to direct sunlight, movement of vehicular traffic, standardized housing units, and proximity to green-space.

Roots of the rational planning movement some from Britain's **Sanitary Movement** (1800-1890). Charles Booth and Ebenezer Howard argued for central organized, top-down solutions to the problems of industrializing cities. For example,London created a network of new communities clustered around the expanding rail system. So what you already have in the space will determine what you might build, like a railway station

The two best examples of this are Letchworth in Hertfordshire and Hampstead Garden Suburb in Greater London.

> In both communities, architects Raymond Unwin and Richard Barry Parker
>   exemplify the elite, top-down approach associated with the rational
>   planning movement by using the planning process to establish a uniform
>   landscape and architectural style based on an idealized medieval
>   village.

Later movements began asking the communities themselves what they valued and looked for input, and some even looked at city planning as a way to correct social inequities. These models are very [participation-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theories_of_urban_planning).

While you might like the idea of all curved roads, it's more difficult to make sense of directionally, and it's easy to get turned around. While round-abouts do help with traffic flow, even when they are present, roads tend to be straight and in a grid, when they are planned. Roads that follow natural features are sometimes in this configuration, and highways/freeways that go all the way around a city can and will be round. Consider Jacksonville, FL.

[image: Jacksonville, FL]

The actual grid of Jacksonville, FL can be a bit of a hodgepdge, mainly owing to the river snaking through it, and a lack of city planning. But, the highway 295 that encircles the city, that's something you will see in a lot of big cities, like Atlanta.

[image]

It's a quick way to get around a city without having to travel through it, a choice made when there is traffic congestion.

You'll learn a lot about these patterns by googling cities and and even looking at the main arteries through and around large cities.

Now, this pattern is distinctly modern, and any mode of transport other than cars as they are now, will change that. European cities have a layout that harkens back, but American cities aren't as old. European city centers are more Medieval (generally, but of course not always).

And, it depends on the density around a city--Southern U.S. cities like Atlanta and Georgia follow that pattern, but more dense places, like Miami, New York, and L.A. might not.

Because there are a million considerations, landowners who refuse to sell land, protected species, a community that wants to build a park in a place that might not make sense for the city grid, but makes sense for that area.

I hope this gives you a start. This question is terribly broad.

Comment: The Romans used a grid system?  In their military camps, yes.  In Rome the city, not so much: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Karte_Rom_unter_Augustus_MKL1888.png  Likewise the Greeks: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Map_ancient_athens.png

Comment: @jamesqf When they were actually planned, yes. But many were not, and were a hodgepodge. http://www.hellenicaworld.com/Greece/Technology/en/CityPlan.html

Comment: @jamesqf I edited to make that clear.